# How do you add a CSS class if the default field value is chosen?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

How do you identify that the default taxonomy field choice has been chosen?

Solution consists of a taxonomy list. If the default is chosen the title in the display should be hidden.

Using views to display the list.

Comment: You __could__ do this at the view stage and rewrite the output if the `field_value == <default>`.

Comment: It might be helpful to know what version of Drupal you're talking about.